# Import null values in MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

I'm importing data with csv in MongoDB Compass, but some values must be null. In MySQL Workbench we use '\N' to import that null values, for MongoDB what i should use?

Answer (score 0):

You can just insert null into mongo.

Note that this is different from not inserting the field at all. 
See the docs below on 'null' and non-existent: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-for-null-fields/